# What's the newest way to get answers from a QnAMaker knowledge base in july 2019?

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to keep my code up to date with azure SDK using the QnAMakerClient however I realize that there is no runtime class at this point included in the nuget package. After checking the SDK repository I can see the runtime class there but it's not included in the latest nuget package.

Based in this scenario what's the newest and recommended way to consume the service without the runtime class?

Comment: I'm not strong in this area, but you might want to check out [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/tree/master/samples/QnAMaker) to see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, but the runtime class is still not available in the latest Nuget package... So let's wait for it

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the SDK from my local side. I tested the latest version (1.1.0) of Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Knowledge.QnAMaker. And after I change the endpoint, all works well. You can refer to the code follows:

```cs
        public static void QnASample()
    {
        var client = new QnAMakerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("<key>")) {
                Endpoint = "https://<name>.cognitiveservices.azure.com"
            };
        // Create a KB
        Console.WriteLine("Creating KB...");
        var kbId = CreateSampleKb(client).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Created KB with ID : {0}", kbId);
        //var kbId = "733ea352-94df-4e57-9fff-216bb38bd423";

        // Update the KB
        Console.WriteLine("Updating KB...");
        UpdateKB(client, kbId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("KB Updated.");

        // Publish the KB
        Console.Write("Publishing KB...");
        client.Knowledgebase.PublishAsync(kbId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("KB Published.");


        //// Download the KB
        //Console.Write("Downloading KB...");
        //var kbData = await client.Knowledgebase.DownloadAsync(kbId, EnvironmentType.Prod);
        //Console.WriteLine("KB Downloaded. It has {0} QnAs.", kbData.QnaDocuments.Count);

        //// Delete the KB
        //Console.Write("Deleting KB...");
        //await client.Knowledgebase.DeleteAsync(kbId);
        //Console.WriteLine("KB Deleted.");
    }


    private static async Task UpdateKB(IQnAMakerClient client, string kbId)
    {
        var updateOp = await client.Knowledgebase.UpdateAsync(kbId, new UpdateKbOperationDTO
        {
            Add = new UpdateKbOperationDTOAdd { QnaList = new List<QnADTO> { new QnADTO { Questions = new List<string> { "bye" }, Answer = "goodbye" } } }
        });

        // Loop while operation is success
        updateOp = await MonitorOperation(client, updateOp);
    }

    private static async Task<string> CreateSampleKb(IQnAMakerClient client)
    {
        var qna = new QnADTO
        {
            Answer = "You can use our REST APIs to manage your knowledge base.",
            Questions = new List<string> { "How do I manage my knowledgebase?" },
            Metadata = new List<MetadataDTO> { new MetadataDTO { Name = "Category", Value = "api" } }
        };

        var urls = new List<string> { "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/faqs" };
        var createKbDto = new CreateKbDTO
        {
            Name = "QnA Maker FAQ from quickstart",
            QnaList = new List<QnADTO> { qna },
            Urls = urls
        };
        var createOp = await client.Knowledgebase.CreateAsync(createKbDto);
        //var createOp = await client.Knowledgebase.CreateAsync(createKbDto);
        createOp = await MonitorOperation(client, createOp);

        return createOp.ResourceLocation.Replace("/knowledgebases/", string.Empty);
    }

    private static async Task<Operation> MonitorOperation(IQnAMakerClient client, Operation operation)
    {
        // Loop while operation is success
        for (int i = 0;
            i < 20 && (operation.OperationState == OperationStateType.NotStarted || operation.OperationState == OperationStateType.Running);
            i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for operation: {0} to complete.", operation.OperationId);
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            operation = await client.Operations.GetDetailsAsync(operation.OperationId);
        }

        if (operation.OperationState != OperationStateType.Succeeded)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Operation {operation.OperationId} failed to completed.");
        }
        return operation;
    }
```

Just pay attention to the endpoint, it is a bit different from the value which the portal shows.

[image]